# CORS request working fine on Chrome but not on Safari/Firefox

Tags: laravel, firefox, safari, cors, axios

**The Problem**

When making a CORS request to login to my app on localhost, I am getting the following error on the latest version of Safari/Firefox running on Sierra.

Doing this exact thing on Chrome however works absolutely fine without any issues. I am using Laravel 5.6+ with CORS enabled properly.

**Safari**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

**Firefox Network tab**

[image]

**/login POST OK, /user GET NOPE**

[image]

**Chrome /user GET (notice Access-Control-Allowed-Origin)**

[image]

But doing the same on Safari/Firefox, on `/user` GET, that header is missing (?)

[image]

**Laravel 5.6 CORS setup**

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => [env('ALLOWED_ORIGINS')],
'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
'allowedHeaders' => ['Origin', 'Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept', 'Authorization'],
'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
'exposedHeaders' => ['*'],
'maxAge' => 0,
```

**The tools**

1. Laravel Mix
2. Laravel 5.6+
3. axios
4. Vue.js 2
5. @websanova/vue-auth

I am also setting the below on axios as defaults. There is no reason that this very code that works on Chrome latest, doesn't work on FF/Safari latest. I have been banging my head against this for hours, to no avail.

```
window.axios = axios;
window.axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that Authorization Bearer gets set for `/user` GET on Chrome, but not on Firefox or Safari. This is absurd. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: The firefox response is 401 and chrome is 200. It's possible the CORS library doesn't send the CORS headers on error responses.

Comment: @apokryfos Please see my update at the very bottom. And no, it actually does send CORS  headers on error responses as well.

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue:

`'exposedHeaders' => ['Authorization'],` had to be explicit in my `cors.php`.

`[]` or `['*']` wasn't liked by Safari and Firefox. Chrome however accepted it. Weird

Now, this appears to be a violation of CORS by Chrome.

It doesn't care whether the Exposed Headers is set properly or not. *It still works.*